# Python global name 'os' no longer defined after calling module

Tags: python, import, module

I'm a rank amateur in python, I'm sure there's a simple solution for this. I'm trying to call a module that uses the os.path.exists function. If I write something like below, the code runs fine.

```
import os
if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
    print 'yes'
```

However, I get this error: "NameError: global name 'os' is not defined" when I call a module as below -

```
import os
import modutest

modutest.test()
```

with this module, (I called it modutest.py)

```
def test():
    if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
        print 'yes'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just import 'os' module in modutest.py as shown below:

```
import os
def test():
    if os.path.exists('text.txt'):
        print 'yes'
```

modutest.py is totally different file, so you have to import 'os' module.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. So I understand that I have to import separately in each module I use.

Comment: Welcome. yep, you have to import.

Comment: There are also builtin functions which will be automatically imported, to see those functions use dir(\_\_builtins\_\_).